# su -c gives "[1] Segmentation fault " in Android (Linux)

Tags: android, linux, segmentation-fault, root, pcap

I am facing this strange problem in my android ,

When I try to run a executable by using :

```
su -c "/path/to/executable"
```

I get this error:

```
[1]   Segmentation fault /path/to/executable
```

however, when i run same code after reaching the specific directory and then changing user to root and then running command :

```
./executable
```

Everything works just fine.

Cant find any problem in the code.

This was working just fine a few days ago, I did change the executable.

Note that executable is made by compiling C-Code.

Any help on whats going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344482/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-error-when-i-exec-pm-on-an-android-device

try this

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
 strace su -c /path/to/executable
```

to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanx, this helped !
The basic problem was, I had made a new file(In the code) in the same directory ie /data/local and I was trying to write it but strace told me its having read only permission , Which I later created in /sdcard/.
This solved the problem

Comment: It's always useful to have strace in your toolbox to detect these problems. If the answer helped you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the program depends on a file in current working directory? Have you tried:

```
su -c "cd /directory; sh programfile"
```