# why do i get a Segmentation fault error when i exec "pm" on an android device?

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, root

my device:htcg14 rooted

i can exec pm on emulator.

But my device does not work.
Before I exec "su",it works fine.

```
shell@android:/ $ pm
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-e] [-u] [FILTER]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
```

But when I exec su,then exec pm,i get an error below.Why?

```
shell@android:/ $ su
su
shell@android:/ # pm
pm
[1] + Stopped (signal)     pm
shell@android:/ # pm
pm
[2] + Stopped (signal)     pm
[1] - Segmentation fault   pm
shell@android:/ # busybox pm
busybox pm
pm: applet not found
[2] + Segmentation fault   pm
1|shell@android:/ #
```

how can i execute pm?
help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your `su` binary - go to `SuperUser` app and check for updates. If that doesn't solve your problem then use some other app like `SuperSU`.

Comment: before exec pm,i export LD_LIBRARY_PATH,then it works fine.thx

Comment: @android_test Great man! It works! export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib

Answer (score 8):

In your established shell session, either remote or local, ensure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envar is set:

```
/ # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Should probably be the accepted answer