# Segmentation Fault executing pm on android

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, root, package-managers

I am able to execute `pm` from the adb shell fine, but I get a segmentation fault if I try and execute it from the terminal.
I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344482/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-error-when-i-exec-pm-on-an-android-device) which suggests a similar problem, but their solution doesn't seem to work.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
01-22 04:04:39.356: D/AndroidRuntime(5059): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-22 04:04:39.356: D/AndroidRuntime(5059): CheckJNI is OFF
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): DexOpt: Some deps went away
01-22 04:04:39.366: E/dalvikvm(5059): /system/framework/ext.jar odex has stale dependencies
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-22 04:04:39.366: D/dalvikvm(5059): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): DexOpt: Some deps went away
01-22 04:04:39.366: E/dalvikvm(5059): /system/framework/framework.jar odex has stale dependencies
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-22 04:04:39.366: D/dalvikvm(5059): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): DexOpt: Some deps went away
01-22 04:04:39.366: E/dalvikvm(5059): /system/framework/android.policy.jar odex has stale dependencies
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-22 04:04:39.366: D/dalvikvm(5059): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): DexOpt: Some deps went away
01-22 04:04:39.366: E/dalvikvm(5059): /system/framework/services.jar odex has stale dependencies
01-22 04:04:39.366: I/dalvikvm(5059): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-22 04:04:39.366: D/dalvikvm(5059): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
01-22 04:04:39.366: D/dalvikvm(5059): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-22 04:04:39.376: D/dalvikvm(5059): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-22 04:04:39.376: D/dalvikvm(5059): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-22 04:04:39.376: D/dalvikvm(5059): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-22 04:04:39.406: I/dalvikvm(5059): DexOpt: Some deps went away
01-22 04:04:39.406: E/dalvikvm(5059): /system/framework/pm.jar odex has stale dependencies
01-22 04:04:39.406: I/dalvikvm(5059): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-22 04:04:39.406: E/appproc(5059): ERROR: could not find class 'com.android.commands.pm.Pm'
01-22 04:04:39.406: E/JNIHelp(5059): Native registration unable to find class 'android/debug/JNITest', aborting
01-22 04:04:39.406: A/libc(5059): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 5059 (app_process)
```

Comment: Which solution did you try on that page. Looks like your library paths aren't set up correctly, as indicated in that other thread.

Comment: I tried exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as suggested, and `root@android:/ # echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` reveals: `/vendor/lib:/system/lib`, which seems okay to me :/

Answer (score 3):

1. Check BOOTCLASSPATH of your init.rc. BOOTCLASSPATH must include /system/framework/ext.jar and /system/framework/framework.jar and so on.
2. Check DEXPREOPT_BOOT_JARS of build/core/dex_preopt.mk. DEXPREOPT_BOOT_JARS must include ext and framework and so on.
3. The order of all items on BOOTCLASSPATH must be equal to the order of all items on DEXPREOPT_BOOT_JARS.